# Limit Trade On Each Pair Using MQL4

Tags: logic, mql4, algorithmic-trading, metatrader4, mql5

I want to limit the number or trades/orders in MT4 using my EA in MQL4. I want the limit on each pair not on all Pairs, like: If the condition / logic match then 2 trades will be executed on Each currency where the EA is attached.

This is the code i tried, but it limits the trades on all pairs where EA has been attached.

```
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                         psar.mq4 |
//|                                                              MSZ |
//|                                                             nill |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#property copyright "MSZ"
#property link      "nill"
#property version   "1.00"
#property strict
#define MAX_ORDERS 5
input int TP=10;
input int SL=30;
input double lot=1;
void OnTick()
  {
//---
   double SAR;
static int Ticket=0;
SAR=iSAR(Symbol(),0,0.02,0.2,0);
if(OrdersTotal()<=MAX_ORDERS)
{
    if(SAR>Open[0])
    {
    Ticket=OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_SELL,lot,Bid,10,Ask+SL*Point,Ask-TP*Point,"Done By MSZ.Inc");
         if(Ticket<0)
         {
         Alert("Error In Opening Order");
         }
         else
         {
      Alert("Sell Order Executed");
     }
      //Alert("Its Sell Signal");

    }

   else if(SAR<Open[0])
    {
     Ticket=OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_BUY,lot,Ask,10,Bid-SL*Point,Bid+TP*Point,"Done By MSZ.Inc");
         if(Ticket<0)
         {
         Alert("Error In Opening Order");
         }
         else
         {
      Alert("Buy Order Executed");
     }
    }
    }
    else
    {
    Alert("Orders Limits reached");
    }
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want that it will execute 5 orders on Each Chart where the EA is attached.

Answer (score 0):

```
**if(OrdersTotal()<=MAX_ORDERS)**
```

This may send up to 6 trades due to the = sign. It will also top up trades either buy or sell at any time until the `<=` condition is met. To clarify, are you meaning to hedge? Your **`MAX_ORDERS`** is defined as a pre-processor directive. `input int MAX_ORDERS =5;` to be able to change this value.

Answer (score 0):

#define MAX_ORDERS 5
After input this at the beginning of the ea script is it necessary to add   **if(OrdersTotal()<=MAX_ORDERS later in the script